# KeyListener is acting differently on a webpage than in Eclipse. What can I do to stop this?

Tags: java, applet, keylistener

I have a java Applet in which I use a Key Listener. When I run it in Eclipse, it runs fine and the way I desire it. I have put it into a webpage, and the Applet behaves differently. I am clueless as to why. I have included my code below, as well as a link to the Applet. I would ideally like to be able to move the small square when I press a button. As it is right now on the webpage, it acts as though I have sticky keys. I do not want this. Also, 'W A S D' do not work to move the square. Only the arrow keys do. I would like both of them to be able to control the rectangle.

Thanks for your help in advance,
  ~Rane

Key Listener:

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        dy = -1;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        dx = 1;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        dy = 1;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        dx = -1;
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
        dy = -1;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D:
        dx = 1;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
        dy = 1;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        dx = -1;
        break;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        dy = 0;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        dx = 0;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        dy = 0;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        dx = 0;
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
        dy = 0;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D:
        dx = 0;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
        dy = 0;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        dx = 0;
        break;
    }

}
```

Moving the square:

```
if(dy < 0)) {
    playerY --;
}
if(dx > 0) {
    playerX ++;
}
if(dy > 0 {
    playerY ++;
}
if(dx < 0) {
    playerX --;
}
```

Drawing the square:

```
 g.drawRect(playerX, playerY, 20, 20);
```

Requesting Focus in class that extends Applet:

```
this.setFocusable(true);
this.requestFocusInWindow();
this.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Yup, `KeyListener` does that.  If you're using a `JApplet`, you can use the Key Bindings API instead, which resolves many of the issues revolving around `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details...

Comment: There is no way around this through a Java Applet then?

Comment: No, you would need to make you applet `focusable` and use `requestFocus` and hope that works...